# When using Webpack to resolve directly to a sibling NPM project, how can I specify a resolve order wrt which node_modules to look at first?

Tags: npm, webpack

I have two npm projects, `project-a` and `project-b`. They both publish and ought to be able to be directly depended upon by any npm project in my company. `project-a` depends on `project-b`. They both live as siblings in the same Git repo.

I want to directly import certain components from `project-b` into `project-a`. I'm very close -- by specifying a `resolve.alias` in `project-a` that looks like `project-b: path.resolve(__dirname, '../project-b/entrypoint.js')` I can pull in what `entrypoint.js` offers. However, when Webpack attempts to resolve what `entrypoint` imports, it looks first in `project-b/node_modules`. This is a problem for two reasons: we use React, so this pulls in multiple copies of React (`project-a/node_modules/react` and `project-b/node_modules/react`), which React users know will break the UI, and similarly it pulls in multiple copies of any shared dependency, of which there are many, leading to a considerable amount of otherwise benign bloat in the Webpack artifact of `project-a`.

My hunch is there must be a way to tell webpack to, when resolving imports in `project-b`, first look in `project-a` and failing that go ahead and look in `project-b`. This way it'll first look in `project-a/node_modules` for `react` whether the import statement is in `project-a` or `project-b`, leading to only `project-a/node_modules` copies of shared dependencies in `project-a`'s artifact, while successfully allowing unique `project-b` dependencies / components to be resolved. I've played around a bunch with `resolve.root`, `resolve.modulesDirectories`, and `resolve.fallback`, but haven't been able to achieve what I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue in my project, also with multiple copies of React being included in the bundle.

The solution is quite simple -- add this to your webpack (version 2) configuration under the `resolve` key:

```
modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"), "node_modules"]
```

This instructs webpack to resolve in `node_modules` within the build directory before resolving in `node_modules` in other directories. In your case, this should mean that the module is grabbed from `project-a/node_modules` instead of `project-b/node_modules`.

You can find more documentation [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules).